# Format numbers in thousands (K) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In MS Excel, I would like to format a number in order to show only thousands and with 'K' in from of it,
so the number 123000 will be displayed in the cell as **123K**

It is easy to format to show only thousands (123), but I'd like to add the K symbol in case the number is > 1000.
so one cell with number 123 will display **123**
one cell with 123000 will show **123K**

Any idea how the format Cell -> custom filters can be used?

Thanks!

Comment: To scale, just add you thousand separator. If it's a comma, the format is <#,K>, without the <>. If it's a space (like for me, in France), it's <# K>. If you want to put a space before K, write <#," K"> or <# " K">. See also [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-a-custom-format-in-excel-to-display-easier-to-read-millions/)

Comment: yep..that's what you want if you want to format even a number like 1.245 -> 1K

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the test :-) The answer below has it the right way.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Custom format

```
[>=1000]#,##0,"K";0
```

will give you:

[image]

Note the comma between the zero and the "K".  To display millions or billions, use two or three commas instead.

Comment: teylyn, this rocks! :)

Comment: I want to add, that (I guess based on punctuation settings) it might as well be `[>=1000]#,###."K";0`

Comment: @JochenReinschlüssel, that's not quite correct. If your regional settings use a comma as the thousand separator, then it needs to be in `[>=1000]#,##0,"K";0` and replacing the second comma with a dot will not work. If your regional settings use a dot as the thousand separator, then, by all means use the dot, but in both places. You will probably also need to replace the semicolon with whatever you use as the list separator.

Comment: This is great. Very helpful. Question - how would you change it so it works on negative numbers as well? e.g. (2,324) will be -2K or (2K) ?
Thanks! EDIT: KISS 0,"k" or $0,"k" for currency.

Comment: Added [>=1000]#,##0,"K";[<=-1000]-#,##0,"K";0 below - which includes negatives.

Comment: How should I extend this to include Millions if its an even bigger number?

Comment: Use the same principle and append the formats with the semicolon. The first  condition that evaluates to TRUE will win and the format will be applied. For example `[>=1000000]#,##0,,"M";[>=1000]#,##0,"K";0`

Comment: In Excel 2016 it doesn't work for me. But `[>=1000]# ##0 "K";0` does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @tm I don't know what you might be doing wrong. It works perfectly fine for me in XL 2016

Comment: @teylyn your comment where you provide custom formatting code for either an M for millions or a K for thousands is brilliant. Just wanted to let you know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 16):

Non-Americans take note! If you use Excel with "." as 1000 separator, you need to replace the "," with a "." in the formula, such as:

```
[>=1000]€ #.##0." K";[<=-1000]-€ #.##0." K";0
```

The code above will display € 62.123 as "€ 62 K".

Comment: I am not getting this.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh European number format standards often use the decimal point (`.`) as a digit grouping character and a comma (`,`) as a decimal point indicator. It's quite confusing to see, especially if you're used to the "American" way.

Comment: @CameronTacklind Unfortunately, I could not recall what I did but I was aware of the number system. I think I was missing out on something else but it had got solve. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 8):

```
[>=1000]#,##0,"K";[<=-1000]-#,##0,"K";0
```

teylyn's answer is great.  This just adds negatives beyond -1000 following the same format.

Answer (score 7):

Enter this in the custom number format field:

```
[>=1000]#,##0,"K€";0"€"
```

What that means is that if the number is greater than 1,000, display at least one digit (indicated by the zero), but no digits after the thousands place, indicated by nothing coming after the comma.  Then you follow the whole thing with the string "K".

*Edited to add comma and euro.*

Comment: Thanks BringMyCakeBack, that works great. I took your logic and added euro sign (since I am working with currency) [>=1000]0,"K€";0,"€".  What would be great is to extend this and keep comma/dot to separate thousands, so one million would be 100,000K. Any idea how to extend it in the custom number format ? Many thanks.

Comment: Yup, you can do that by combining the usual thousands separator syntax.  I've updated my answer, and it looks like teylyn was thinking the same thing.  Also, be careful to not put a comma after the last zero like in your comment -- that will transform all low numbers to 0.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Simple and clean!

Answer (score 5):

The examples above use a 'K'  an uppercase k used to represent kilo or 1000. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-), `kilo` or 1000's should be represented in **lower** case. So, rather than £300K, use    £300k or in a code example :-

```
[>=1000]£#,##0,"k";[red][<=-1000]-£#,##0,"k";0
```

Comment: To nitpick, the wiki article you link refers to the use of lower-case k as a *prefix* to SI unit symbols, so 1000 m becomes 1 km, 1000 g becomes 1 kg etc.  It doesn't say anything about using K as a suffix, and in my experience upper-case K is more common.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following combination that works fine for positive and negative numbers (**43787200020 is transformed to  43.787.200,02 K**)

> [>=1000] #.##0,#0. "K";#.##0,#0. "K"

Comment: to have numbers between -1000 and 1000 not formated use the following custom format: **[>=1000] #.##0,#0. "K";[<=-1000] -#.##0,#0. "K";Standard**