# Format Code to make Currency Number into K and Percentage show in Pie chart Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet with a Pie graph. I wanted the Pie graph to show the number in 'k' when it's over 1000$ and to show the percentage.

I have the following custom format code but it's not working : [>=1000]$#,##0"K";0%

The only Label Options that are checked are value and percentage.

This option shows me the following '57,673,00,3%' opposed to '57k,3%' which is what I want.

Thank you,

George

Comment: The numbers/data that I use are in the 'currency format'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275247/format-numbers-in-thousands-k-in-excel