# Format 1234 as 1.2K in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to format numbers in Excel to use a K to represent thousands but I would like to have numbers displayed to the nearest hundred not just the nearest thousand. I would also like to include a $ sign and () for negative numbers. Is this possible using a custom number format?

[image]

Comment: Similar question here, but does not include the hundreds digit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275247/format-numbers-in-thousands-k-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format numbers in thousands (K) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275247/format-numbers-in-thousands-k-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come close with **custom number formatting**:

```
[>=1000]$* #,##0.0,"K";[<0]$* (0);$* 0
```

Since number formatting only has three number format types, you can make a special case for `0` using **conditional formatting** for cells containing `0`

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that you were only allowed three number formats. That explains the errors I got with formats that I had tried like [>=1000] ... ;[<=-1000] ... ;[<0] ... ;[=0] ... ; ... 

Not perfect, but I think this is as close as we'll get with that restriction of 3 conditions.

Comment: @YesIuseMUMPS Yes, you'll need to use the conditional formatting method (or VBA) for your "fourth" formatting option.