# How to sort electronics values with suffixes (k, m, g, uF, H, etc.)?

Tags: excel, sorting

How to sort rows when a column has standard electronics "suffixes"?

I see many questions here that are close, but most go the other way, like 
 [Format numbers in thousands (K) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275247/format-numbers-in-thousands-k-in-excel)

Anyone in electronics will immediately appreciate this problem. I have lots of parts lists, and am pasting values into Excel/GSheets. They are standard suffixes, but clearly not solely numbers. Here is a representative sample:

```
A       B       C       D
RA367   0603    2.2     5% 1/10w MF-LF
RA770   0201    5.1k    1% 1/20w MF
RA775   0201    5.1k    1% 1/20w MF
RB600   0402    0       5% 1/16w MF-LF
RB604   0201    0       5% 1/20w MF
```

Only column C is needed to sort. The suffixes vary on the type of component, but are not mixed when sorted. In other words, you would never sort a column of 'mixed' components such as:

```
2.5k
1.0pF
10m
20uF
2 kOhms
[...]
```

The mutiplier portion of the suffixes would always be the same, as in R, k, m, , are typically resistors; pF, F, and uF are capacitors, H, uH, etc. is for inductors (for Henries), etc. So it is best if "conversion" for sorting consider only the first character (u, p, k, m, R) which are always the *multiplier*, and if no multiplier character (as in the 0 in the first example) just sort as a number.

```
1.1       = 1.1
1.1 k     = 1100
1.1k      = 1100
1.1kOhms  = 1100
1.1k Ohms = 1100
[...]
```

This is because lots of parts listings will omit the type of value (resistor, capacitor, etc.) and only give the base number (1, 2, 40, 1m, 2.2k, ...). his is because again, values of different components are never mixed.

Here is a real-world snippet from a large distributor, from a downloaded CSV:

```
[...]
0 Ohms
100 kOhms
100 kOhms
100 kOhms
1 MOhms
1 MOhms
1 MOhms
100 Ohms
100 Ohms
100 Ohms
49.9 Ohms
[...]
```

Here you can see how the default sorting on first, second character fails, and that there is even a space between the base and multiplier. A solution should not have to worry about a finite list of *types* of components, ignoring the Ohms, R, H, F, etc. after the value is determined by the base and optional multiplier.

These are the only two ways you will see components listed-with or without that space. I am wondering if there is a single, elegant function to apply to a range, or if multiple ones are needed based on the space introduced in the second example.

This may seem like an obscure problem, but large suppliers offer CSV downloads of their products, and when you need to order, and are combining lists in different formats, it becomes *most* cumbersome.

Comment: Does m ever occur meaning milli- ? I'm thinking the others are OK, but there might be an issue separating m from M meaning meg- ?

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `IFS()` function ??

Comment: To answer my own question, you can indeed have a 10mH choke meaning milliHenry and you can have a 10Mohm resistor meaning megohm, so it looks to me as though you would have to sort inductors and resistors a bit differently (because you can't rely on the m always being capitalised).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for resistors and capacitors, assuming m meaning milli- isn't used:

```
=sort(A:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"[0-9.]+")*1000^(search(iferror(regexextract(A:A,"[0-9.]+\s*([pukmKM])")," "),"pux km")-4),1)
```

(I know you wouldn't mix them, but this is just to demonstrate)

[image]

Comment: I appreciate how the regex chars are [grouped] so they can be modified. I could just write separate functions for each type of component, i.e. sortResistors(), sortInductors(), etc. as it is unreasonable to ask that one function do it all... I was unaware of the function REGEXTRACT or it's utility. Awesome!